What is the solar radiative power on a clear sky day through a surface which is parallel to the sun's incidence on Earth?
Assuming that the solar power through the incident surface is known. How can we calculate or estimate the radiation through the parallel surface assuming a clear sky?
Looking for watts per square meter, effectively, through a window

Are you looking for Watts per square meter as one would want for, e.g., solar panels?

@JonCuster yes.

Google "solar insolation calculator" and pick one... Getting historical data on actual insolation by region is pretty easy these days as well.

what does latitude mean. How do i set the angle of the test surface vector to parallel the ground?

Go to Google maps, click on a spot near your address. A little box pops up with two numbers in it - the first is latitude (how far north/south of the equator you are) and the second is longitude (how far east/west of the Greenwich meridian you are).
